# How to perform concurrent reads from hazelcast RingBuffer in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast

We have a hazelcast cluster(5.3.2) deployed in our architecture. There are multiple threads from application A producing data into a RingBuffer. There is a consumer application (application B) that has runs in a single thread and reads data from this RingBuffer. This data reading method is turning out to be slow. The producer and consumer are both java spring boot applications using hazelcast client library to connect with hazelcast. The consumer application thread uses the `ringbuffer.readOne(sequence)`  method to read from ringbuffer.

How can I speed the data reads from a ringbuffer **by using multiple threads**? Please share code samples that I can refer to.

Thanks.

Comment: create another thread-group and pass on that work to those threads. Not sure you want to commit your read msg from ring buffer until you process your task.

Comment: 1. What method call on the client indicate the commit of msg read? 
2. Are you suggesting we read from the ringbuffer through a single thread but process it in another thread group? We have tried that but doesn't help much. Processing the message isn't a time consuming operation. 
Reading with multiple threads is something that would speed up consumer application. Any code samples for that?

Comment: if processing is not much of efforts , then can't you just create multiple threads to consume from ring buffer and have some Global synchronous counter in order avoid contention while consuming which same you asked at end of 2nd question in above comment as well as same suggested in below answer

Comment: code sample will be easy to add if u have some dummy code available in question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might try to use `readManyAsync` instead of `readOne`. You will amortize the time needed for network roundtrip compared to `readOne` which uses network for each item:

```
CompletionStage<ReadResultSet<Integer>> result = 
    ringbuffer.readManyAsync(sequence, 1, 1000, null);
```

If that doesn't help (or doesn't help enough) you might use the Ringbuffer instance from multiple threads - it's thread-safe, you just need to make sure that different threads read different sections of the ringbuffer.

Comment: > make sure that different threads read different sections of the ringbuffer. - That's a code sample I am looking for. 
1. How do we make different threads read different sections?
2. We won't know the size of the ring buffer upfront so as to read different sections. Both the producer and consumer applications run in parallel. So during peak times the ringbuffer size is big while it reduces otherwise.

Comment: To find out number of available items you can call the `tailSequence` and `headSequence` methods on the ringbuffer. The rest should be Java 101.

Comment: When we pass the `headSequence` to multiple threads, hazelcast isn't able to determine the current sequence number leading to race conditions. I think this happens because hazelcast waits for a commit on the record read operation. I do not know how does the client signal this commit. If you have a working sample of concurrent readers to hazelcast ringbuffer or can point me to something existing it would be a great help. Thanks